# Can I Fetch Data from API while using a variable to change the url target? [SwiftUI]

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a question. I am trying to make a API call to fetch data for a specific item. To do so, I just need to modify 1 parameter of the URL that is making the call.

This is the call on the item page to fetch the data. I feel like I should be able to pass the item # like this. But im having trouble passing it correctly.

```
struct ProductPage: View {
    
@ObservedObject var relatedsectionNetwork = RelatedSectionAPI()

...
...

.onAppear() {
            relatedsectionNetwork.fetchData(prID: "1824085")
            print("relatedSection Loaded")
        }
```

This is the actual class and function that I am using to make the call. You can see what my thought process was here: create a var that could be used to change the prID within the URL.
class RelatedSectionAPI: ObservableObject {

```
var prID : String = ""

func fetchData() {
    
    print("fetchData3 -start ")
    if let url = URL(string:"https://www.*****.com/****/******?***=***=&***=&***=***&pr_id=\(prID)&***") {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
             if error == nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
```

I cut this part short to not confuse anyone.
If any one can please help me out, or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Add the parameter to the function call `func fetchData(prID: String = "")`. BTW you should use `@StateObject` vs `@ObservedObject` when you initialize an `ObservableObject` in a `View`

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you! I knew it would be something simple. I had originally tried to pass the variable via the function call, but looks like I failed by not declaring it a String in the param... And also thank you for informing me the correct way to initialize an Observable Object in a View! This is a huge help.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I added my comment as an answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the parameter to the function call `func fetchData(prID: String = "")`. BTW you should use `@StateObject` vs `@ObservedObject` when you initialize an `ObservableObject` in a `View`